# AttributeError when trying to print describe()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning to do statistical analysis with Python. After successfully loading my dataset and trying to print out the statistics of the dataset gives me an attribute error. Here is my code:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ME/dataset1.csv', sep=',')
print.my_data.describe()
```

Here is what I am getting back.

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'my_data'
```

I fixed the problem using

```
 print(my_data(describe))
```

but still would like to know why print.my_data.describe() didn't work.

Comment: `print` is a method, not a package.

Comment: The question is more why you expected `print.my_data` *to* work? Where did you pick up that the `print` function would have `my_data` as an attribute? If that's a public source then that could perhaps be corrected.

Comment: Also, `print(my_data(describe))` would not work *either*. [`describe()` is a method on a dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html), presumably you are trying to print the return value, so you'd use `print(my_data.describe())`. `my_data.describe` accesses the method (it is an attribute), then `()` calls that method, and the *result* of that call is passed to the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the print function does not have an attribute named my_data. Coincidentally this is what the error message says

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Use `print(my_data.describe())`

---

I think a better question to ask(as @ MartijnPieters has already mentioned), Is where did you get the idea that `print.my_data` would work?

`print()` is a builtin function in Python that allows you to output data to your terminal. From [the Python docs on `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print):

> [The print function] print[s] objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.

---

Taking the information above, we can deduce that `print()` is a function.
To use a function in Python(and pretty much every other programming language), you must call it using the `()` operator. When calling a function, you put the functions arguments  inside of the `()`'s eg.

```
>>> print("Hello World")
Hello World
>>> print("Goodbye World")
Goodbye World
>>> print(1)
1
>>> print(2)
2
>>>
```

After reading this information, your problem should be clear. **Your using the print function the wrong way. You need to call the `print()` function, not try to get one of its attributes.**

Thus, the correct way to print the return value of `my_data.describe()` is to write:

`print(my_data.describe())`